# How to prevent users from renaming the sheet name

Tags: excel, macos, office-js

Is there an api to do this? I can't find the api but it's really an important function for me, so want to make a confirmation.

[image: sheets still can be renamed after protection]

sheets still can be renamed after setting protection

excel version: 16.16.4

MacOs: 10.13.6

Comment: Try using the [workbook.protection.protect(password)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.workbookprotection?view=office-js#protect-password-) method. If that works, I'll make it the answer.

Comment: @RickKirkham  It doesn't work, still can be renamed.

Answer (score 0):

This code prevents any of the sheets from being renamed:

```
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const workbook = context.workbook;
    workbook.protection.protect("myPassword");
    await context.sync();
});
```

Comment: Sheets still can be renamed after protection, please see the screenshot in my question

Comment: I see that you've added to your answer that you are on a Mac. I was working on Windows. I cannot reproduce the symptoms on Windows, so I think this is probably a bug in Office for Mac. I recommend at this time that you raise an issue on this repo: [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/)